# IIS FTP client in Windows 2000 setup

Tags: ftp, windows-2000, iis

Using Windows 2000 Pro with IIS 5.

I'm going to have an FTP Server send files to this box to store, and need to set up the FTP client architecture right.  The dialogs look easy to setup the box as a FTP server if I wanted to, but not sure what to do to setup the client besides creating a specific user account.

Comment: Are you sure that Windows 2000 is the best option for this?  Totally unsupported and likley has some security issues.

Comment: It's on a "secure" network, not connected to the net.

Comment: I'm no FTP guru, and realize that I might be stretching the meaning of FTP client here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to go through the FTP Server setup process.

I disabled anonymous FTP, and setup a specific account and a specific directory for the files to be transferred to.